# Solving PDE employing eigenfunction method.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please how can this be solved using the eignfunction expansion method. I have very little knowledge about it.

$$P_1\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) + P_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\right) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$$ with boundary conditions

$$u(e^{-\pi}, t) = 0, \ \ u(e^{\pi}, t) = 0, \ \ u( y, 0 ) = 0$$
where $ P_1 $ and $ P_2 $ are constants

Comment: Why do you use $P$s for constants? I think many people would wrongly assume they are polynomials.

Comment: Take $u=f(y) g(t)$, substitute in equation and then divide by $fg$. Separate the result into a time dependent and a y-dependent part. Solve the time dependnt equation. The y dependent part is of Sturm - Liouville type equation that gives eigenfunctions. Take an expansion in terms of these functions, impose boundary conditions, and then multiply solution by $g(t)$.

Comment: HR-Physics a mathematical demonstration would be appreciated

Comment: @ HR-physics, gotten it. thanks